# How can the Higgs have so many different Yukawa couplings?

Tags: particle-physics

How can the Higgs have so many Yukawa couplings?  Isn't this about the same as saying the Higgs has a force or charge for each different coupling?  Is this some indication of substructure for the Higgs or some kind of mixing with other scalar neutral particles that have not been found yet?

Answer (score 3):

It has different yukawa couplings with all of the fundamental particles because this is allowed by the symmetries of the standard model, and if this were different, the standard model wouldn't accurately predict physics.

Whether some theory that envelops the standard model will have a way of predicting the yukawa couplings is, of course, an active area of research.

Answer (score 2):

The Higgs particle and the Higgs field do constitute a 5th force - in addition to the nuclear (color force), the electric, the weak and the gravitational force. The coupling to each particle becomes the mass term for that particle due to the non-zero value of the Higgs field.  As Prof Matt Strassler says (in http://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/the-known-forces-of-nature/the-strength-of-the-known-forces/ ):

> **The Higgs Force!?**
>
> As of 2012, we have a new force to think about: the force between two
>   particles induced by the Higgs field! This is not to be confused with
>   the effect by which the Higgs field gives the known elementary
>   particles their masses; the Higgs field can do this to a single,
>   isolated particle. That’s not a force; it doesn’t push or pull.  But
>   the Higgs field can also induce a force between two particles; this
>   happens in much the same way that electromagnetic forces are created. 
>   However, as far as its effect on ordinary matter, this force is very,
>   very hard to detect.  At short distances, for particles like electrons
>   and the up and down quarks that dominate the proton, the Higgs force
>   is very weak (much weaker than electromagnetism, but much much
>   stronger than gravity).  At long distances, like the weak nuclear
>   force, the Higgs force becomes extremely weak, because the Higgs
>   particle, like the W particle, has a mass.
>
> The Higgs field induces a force similar to the weak nuclear force in
>   that it has a very short range, becoming ineffectual at distances long
>   compared to ℏ c / Mh ~ 2 × 10-18 meters (1/500 of a proton’s radius),
>   where Mh ≈ 125 GeV/c² is the Higgs particle’s mass. And at first
>   glance the formula is similar to that of gravity, in that it is an
>   attractive force proportional to the masses m of the two elementary
>   particles being attracted.
>
> - αHiggs = (mc2 /4 π v)2  × $e^{-Mhr/ℏc}$  --(for r »  2 × 10-18 meters)
> - αHiggs = (mc2 /4 π v)2    --(for r «  2 × 10-18 meters)
>
> where v = 246 GeV is the constant value of the Higgs field found throughout
>   the universe. [Actually, if one is careful, there is an extra square
>   root of 2 in there, but let's keep the formulas simple-looking.]
>
> Be cautious!  The resemblance to gravity is misleading. This formula
>   is only precise for the known elementary particles — those objects
>   that get their mass from the Higgs field. It works for electrons and
>   muons and quarks.  It is not correct for protons, neutrons, atoms, or
>   you! That’s because a proton’s mass (and a neutrons, and therefore an
>   atom’s, and therefore yours) does not entirely come from the Higgs
>   field. This is in contrast to the formula for gravity, which is
>   correct for all slow objects! Instead, for ordinary atomic matter,
>   we’d have to replace the formula with one that looks similar but has a
>   different factor in front, slightly different for each atom.
>   Qualitatively, however, the dependence on the distance would remain
>   similar.
>
> Also, the formula I’ve written also assumes there is only one Higgs
>   field and one Higgs particle (which we don’t yet know to be true, but
>   is the simplest possibility consistent with current data.) If that’s
>   not the case the formula will become more complicated, while remaining
>   of a similar form.
>   [image]
>   *Fig. 2: The relative strengths (α) for each force, as a function of
>   radius, between about 1/300 of a proton's radius and 30 proton radii. 
>   Fig. 2: The relative strengths (α) for the forces acting on a top
>   quark and top anti-quark, with mass almost 200 times larger than a
>   proton, as a function of radius, between about 1/3000 of a proton’s
>   radius and 30 proton radii.  The Higgs force and the weak nuclear
>   force become extremely weak at distances even smaller than the proton
>   radius, while the strong nuclear force becomes strong at the proton
>   radius. Electromagnetism stays moderately weak at all distances. 
>   There are subtleties, ignored here, involving electromagnetism and the
>   weak nuclear force at sufficiently short distances (grey box). Gravity
>   is incredibly weak and lies far below this graph.  For the up and down
>   quarks in the proton and neutron, the graph would be similar, except
>   that the Higgs force would be far too small to appear on the plot; the
>   same would be true for two electrons, though it is unaffected by the
>   strong nuclear force.*
>
> How strong is this force? Well, at very short
>   distances, shorter than 2 × 10-18 meters, the Higgs force between two
>   top quarks is comparable to the strong nuclear force at that distance
>   (see Figure 2)! But for electrons, which have a low mass because their
>   interaction with the Higgs field is small, the force even at  short
>   distances would be much weaker than electric forces — more than a
>   thousand million times weaker — though still thousands of millions of
>   millions of times stronger than gravitational forces between
>   electrons. Yet if you consider two electrons in an atom, which are
>   about ten million or so times further apart than 2 × 10-18 meters,
>   then the Higgs force between them is much, much smaller even than the
>   tiny gravitational force between them, as it is suppressed by
>   e-10,000,000. [Even if the Higgs field did give protons and neutrons
>   all their masses, the Higgs forces inside a nucleus would still be
>   vastly smaller than those of gravity, which in turn are incredibly
>   small compared to the residual strong nuclear force that holds the
>   nuclei together.]
>
> It is the incredible weakness of the Higgs force in the context of
>   ordinary matter that makes it so hard to discover. On the one hand,
>   the Higgs force, like gravity, is always attractive and can’t be
>   cancelled.  But on the other hand, that’s irrelevant, because, like
>   the weak nuclear force, the Higgs force does not survive to long
>   distance, because the Higgs particle, like the W particle, has a mass.
>   The Higgs force at ultra-short distances is much stronger than
>   gravity, but at nuclear and atomic distances, it is much weaker,
>   because of the Higgs particle’s mass. And for the low-mass particles
>   out of which we’re made, which interact weakly with the Higgs field,
>   the Higgs force is always thousands of millions of times weaker than
>   electric forces, even at very short distances.  So even though every
>   atom in the Earth exerts a Higgs force on every other atom in the
>   Earth, that force is so incredibly minuscule, even for neighboring
>   atoms, and especially for distant ones, that it has no detectable
>   effect.  This is why we had to go find the Higgs particle directly to
>   confirm the Higgs field exists; we couldn’t just go looking for the
>   force it creates, the way we can use the observation of electric and
>   magnetic forces to confirm that the world has electric and magnetic
>   fields.
>
> When might we actually observe this new force? It’s effects will first
>   be observed either in the scattering of W and Z particles off each
>   other (which will eventually be done, indirectly, within the
>   proton-proton collisions at the Large Hadron Collider) or in the
>   interaction between a top quark and a top anti-quark (which can be
>   observed at an electron-positron collider — in fact I wrote my first
>   particle physics paper [see in particular Figure 11 of the paper]
>   about this very phenomenon.)